# Linux - Jail users into their directories

Tags: chroot, vsftpd, proftpd

I want to jail users to their directory in `/home`

I tried to use `vsftpd` with settings:

```
local_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
```

But it doesnt work properly. Users still have access to directories upper own folder.

Then i tried to use `proftpd` with setting:

```
DefaultRoot ~
```

But it doesnt still jail.

Restarted services, also tried to restart server. But both are not jail users.

Answer (score 0):

That is extremely uncivil behaviour, as in a Unixy system much of "getting any job done" requires moving more or less freely through the system, and using all sort of not-in-the-account resources. Correctly set permissions on the more delicate parts, careful configuration, installing only what is required are the ways of restricting bad behaviour by users.

For *very* special uses, you have restricted shells and other restricted commands. Look for "restricted shell", setting that one as the user's shell is an effective way of restricting their activities.